# Swift error handling when converting a file to string

Tags: ios, swift, ios10

**Background**

I am writing an application that downloads a file from a webview. When the file is downloaded I am checking to see if it exist with no problems.

**Problem**

When I try to convert the file to a string so I can manipulate the data I get the infamous

> Call can throw, but it is not marked with 'try' and the error is not
>   handled

I have tried to figure out how to handle the error, but I think in the context of the way I am creating the variable `content`, I am lacking the understanding to complete this task.

**Example**

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {

            if let url = navigationAction.request.url, url.lastPathComponent == "mydata.do" {
                FileDownloader.download(from: url) { filepath in
                    let filemgr = FileManager.default

                    if filemgr.fileExists(atPath: filepath) {
      // this line throws error  
let content = String(contentsOfFile: filepath, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
                        print(content)
                    } else {
                        print("FILES DOES NOT EXIST!")
                    }
                }
                decisionHandler(.cancel)
            } else {
                decisionHandler(.allow)
            }
        }
```

**Question**

What is the proper way to read the file to a string and handle the error when creating the variable the string will be in? In my case `content`.

```
let content = String(contentsOfFile: filepath, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
```

Comment: You should read the doc of the method: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1412610-init and the part showing how to manage Errors in the discussion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should wrap you code into a `do-catch` block with `try` and catch the `error` if there are any:

```
do {
    let data = try String(contentsOfFile: filepath, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
    print(data)
} catch let error as NSError {

}
```

You´ll probably see this syntax with `try!` which will remove the error, but this will crash if any error occurs, so I can recommend the `do-catch` solution.